# Python web framework for I/O intensive page

Tags: python, web, frameworks, io

I have a very I/O intensive task (it crawls webpages). I want to make this task available via a web API and built some JavaScript+HTML interface on top of it. And I want to do it in Python, since I already have a set of Python scripts implementing this task.

Now I'm looking for a Python web framework to do this. **What web framework can you recommend for a very I/O intensive web page?**

Some more details:

- I already worked with Flask and I liked it
- I don't need user management, but I need sessions
- I want to build the actual UI with Angular/Ember

Comment: Recommendation: build your crawler as one process. Build your web interface as a totally separate project that queries the same backing store (RDBMS, NoSQL store, etc.). They're likely to have entirely different needs so it's not likely a good idea to make a "super project" containing all the moving parts inside one framework.

Comment: The idea is to crawl "on demand" since I need the password and the email of the user to crawl. So I can only crawl when a user logs in. And I don't want to store anything, because that would mean that I need user management, a database and all of this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's about web crawling, I'd go with [Scrapy](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org) as a crawling tool and [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) event-driven networking engine/web-framework. `Scrapy` is actually built on top of twisted, so this set might be a good choice for you.

Also, take a look at [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) web framework that is using non-blocking I/O.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) is the most popular web framework for Python.

Comment: Yes. But does it make any difference compared to Flask when it comes to very long running I/O bound tasks?